# What is the "Auto Open Form" checkbox used for?

Tags: qgis

Windows 7 
QGIS 2.6 - 64 bit
Feature - Identify Results

Could someone help me understand what is "Auto Open Form" checkbox used for.

Comment: I checked this option, just to see what happened. But now I want to have the original Identify dialog back. Where can I uncheck this feature? I am using QGIS 2.6.1

Comment: @GerarddeWit - Goto View - Panels - Identify Results, uncheck "Auto open form" checkbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a single feature is identified with the tool the behaviors differ in:

- If the option is checked, the feature form will open, allowing you to make changes to the feature's attributes
- If the option is not checked, the attributes will be shown read-only in the identify feature dockable dialog.

Answer (score 0):

y con codigo seria [How to set checked "Auto Open Form" in identify results window, programatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298192/how-to-set-checked-auto-open-form-in-identify-results-window-programatically)

You have two ways for this

Simple way

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue('/Map/identifyAutoFeatureForm','true')
```

Work but QCheckBox not show checked

And better way (Only if idetify results window is open)

```
QgsIdentifyResultsBase = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog,'QgsIdentifyResultsBase')
cbxAutoFeatureForm = QgsIdentifyResultsBase.findChildren(QCheckBox,'cbxAutoFeatureForm')
cbxAutoFeatureForm[0].setChecked(2)
```

And QCheckBox show checked.