# How to set checked "Auto Open Form" in identify results window, programatically?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to set check programmatically "Auto Open Form" check box in Identify Results window. Window is here and the check box is at the bottom-right:

[image]

The Identify Results window is not open at that time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways for this

**Simple way**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue('/Map/identifyAutoFeatureForm','true')
```

Work but QCheckBox not show checked

And **better way** (Only if idetify results window is open)

```
QgsIdentifyResultsBase = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog,'QgsIdentifyResultsBase')
cbxAutoFeatureForm = QgsIdentifyResultsBase.findChildren(QCheckBox,'cbxAutoFeatureForm')
cbxAutoFeatureForm[0].setChecked(2)
```

And QCheckBox show checked

I hope this helps you

Comment: Francisco, thanks for reply but I forgot that the idetify results window is not open at that time so the second way is not working as you guess. First solution is good but it despite the check box is not checked, it shows as checked and vice versa.

Comment: if is correct,please check the answer with correct