# Showing attributes form when modifying features

Tags: qgis, modify-interaction

QGIS has this neat feature to show up a form, allowing to set/change attribute values, when adding features to a layer, called [attributes form](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html). It is possible to show or hide it when **adding new features**:

[image]

However, I would like to show up this form also when **modifying geometries of already existing features**. For example if I move a point to another location.

Of course I could simply open the attribute table afterwards or use identify tool to show up the form after I moved it. But I am looking for a way to automatically show up the form when e.g. moving features, just like it does when adding new features.

Any ideas how (or if) this could be done? I couldn't find any settings in QGIS 3.4 nor 3.14, only the checkbox to "apply default value on update". This indeed updates values when moving a feature, but does not open the form so users could add extra infos.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can make this form show up with the [identify tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify) and edit the fields of the identified feature if you are in edit mode

[image]

But to my knowledge you can't just link the form to any action.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try copying into the Python startup code configuration panel (icon next to the drag and drop designer) what is suggested in this post:

[How to set checked "Auto Open Form" in identify results window, programatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298192/how-to-set-checked-auto-open-form-in-identify-results-window-programatically)